# Unable To Bind To Other Port with UseUrls

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

The following code just won't change the port to 9874. It stays the same in Project -> Debug -> Web Server Settings -> App URL -> "http://localhost:56021/", which uses the 56021 port. I am using VS 2017 to create .net core webapi project.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:9874")
        .Build();
```

It is the same even i change to Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by changing launchSettings.json.

If the setting is set in the above file, then what is the point to have UseUrls as it always refer to launchsettings.json setting?

Answer (score 1):

In `Project -> Debug -> Web Server Settings` you see is a project profile that is used only when you try to run app from VS.

And in VS this is the responsibility of `launchSettings.json` to store and retrieve project configuration settings needed **to run a project from VS only**. In other words, `launchSettings.json` is ignored if you run app outside of VS (let's say from command line for example).

And back to `.UseUrls` method: it doesn't (and cannot, mainly because your app doesn't know about profiles at all) change above project profiles. Yes, this method indicates the IP addresses or host addresses with ports and protocols that the server should listen on for requests. But those settings will be applied to the Server instance that will be created on app start.